# How to correctly minify angularJS file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, minify

I have a simple angularjs directive and when I minify the file i get error because the variable names are changed

```
var app= angular.module('app',[]);

app.directive('directive',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {},
        replace: true,
        link: function($scope, element, attributes){
            $scope.name="test-test";
        ,
        controller: function($scope,$attrs,$http){

        },
        templateUrl: 'directives/app/app.tpl.html'
    }
});
```

the problem is $scope.name changes into a.name and angular doesn't recognize it. 
I tried injecting $scope by trying something like

```
link: ['$scope',function($scope, element, attributes){
            $scope.name="test-test";
}],
controller: ['$scope','$attrs','$http',function($scope,$attrs,$http){

}],
```

but I still get the same error of a.name when minified.

Comment: The link function doesn't use dependency injection. Is this actually the exact code you are testing? With your original code the link function should work fine and your controller should throw an error about unknown providers

Comment: yes  this is the exact code (i am new to angularJS and playing around with it). It did throw the error before but after tried to inject it does not throw any error but the data binding does not work and I see a.name instead of $scope.name

Comment: Are you intentionally trying to use `$scope` in stead of `scope` in your link function, even though you have specified an isolated scope in your directive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directives `link` functions aren't injected. They're passed fixed set of parameters which are listed and comprehensively described in [angular.js documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object). However this is not the case with `controller`. These are injected and should be annotated before minification. You can do it in at least 3 ways:

- using array syntax like in your example
- setting `$inject` property on controller function with value being array of names of injectables
- annotating with [ngAnnotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) which will detect uses of angular injection and annotate it properly

Answer (score 0):

The link function is not dependency injected. It uses only positional arguments so you don't have to use that explicit array naming. The controller one is fine I think.

At last, remember, you must write code for clarity. The explicit syntax is a bit too verbose, that's why most people choose to use [`ng-annotate`](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) instead. Ng-annotate is a compilation step which will convert the code to the explicit form before minification.